# Don't know the syntax to stop this infinte loop

Tags: javascript

So I'm in a discord server and have a bot. This bot has the following code:

```
if(message.content == 'mass effect' || 'mass' || 'andromeda'){
    function mass() {
        message.channel.send('Mass Effect Andromeda is a good game.');
    }
    mass();
}
```

Now, the statement that the bot says is obviously part of the requirements for the if statement. So when it says "Mass Effect Andromeda is a good game", it continuously loops. It works but unfortunately loops infinitely. I'm not too sure how to fix that...

Answer (score 4):

The expression:

```
message.content == 'mass effect' || 'mass' || 'andromeda'
```

will return true if *message.content* is 'mass effect', or if 'mass' is truthy (which it is) or 'andromeda' is truthy (which it is). I.e., it will always return true.

It should probably be:

```
message.content == 'mass effect' || message.content == 'mass' || message.content == 'andromeda'
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! I thought adding in the message.content was being redundant.

Comment: an alternative could be `if (['mass effect', 'mass', 'andromeda'].indexOf(message.content) > -1)`

Comment: @Gonzalo.-—there are many alternatives, but the focus was to show how to fix the OP's code. My preference would be `/^(mass effect|mass|andromeda)$/.test(message.content)`.